# query over grid.py

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

Facing some problem with grid.py of libsvm. Tried implementing it, but gave syntax error.

Typed:

```
grid.py -svmtrain "c:\Users\HP\Documents\MATLAB\libsvm-3.11\windows\svmtrain.exe" -gnuplot c:\Downloads\gp444win32\gnuplot\binary\pgnuplot.exe-v 10 TrainVec
```

Error :

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what might be the error?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space in `pgnuplot.exe-v`?

Comment: but the point that the syntax error is pointing to is at the end of svmtrain.exe. ' " ' is bold in red...

Comment: is this `c:\Downloads\gp444win32\gnuplot\binary\pgnuplot.exe-v` a valid path?