# Getting grid.py to work in LIBSVM to do grid search

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, libsvm

I have seen that many people especially those with no experience in python struggling to get grid.py to work and facing a lot of errors.Even til today, i am not able to get it to run. I think it would be better if someone who can run it successfully explain each step in detail so that for those in future have difficulty in running it can look at this post.

Thanks in advance

Examples:

[query over grid.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937358/query-over-grid-py)

[how can i use grid.py for parameter selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948034/how-can-i-use-grid-py-for-parameter-selection)

Comment: What is your actual question?  It would be a lot easier to answer if you had an example and the errors you are seeing.